# Find all possible knight move on chess board within the limit, with recursion, C language

Tags: c, function, recursion

So I tried to make a program that shows you all the possible knight moves within the limit, the possible move marked with the number '1'. but when I run the program with a movement limit more than 2, it's kind of messed up. what did I do wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int xpos[8]={2,1,-1,-2,-2,-1,1,2};
int ypos[8]={1,2,2,1,-1,-2,-2,-1};
void whiteMove(int wx, int wy,int map[8][8],int limit);


int main(){
    
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int map[8][8]={{0}};
        int limit; char k1[3];

        scanf("%d",&limit);getchar();
        scanf("%s",k1);getchar();

        int wx=k1[0]-'A';
        int wy='8'-k1[1];

        printf("Case #%d: \n",i+1);
        whiteMove(wx,wy,map,limit+1);
    
    
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<8;k++){
                printf("%d ",map[j][k]);
            }
            puts("");
        }
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void whiteMove(int wx, int wy,int map[8][8], int limit){
        
    if(wx<0||wy<0||wx>7||wy>7||limit==0){
        return;
    }else if(map[wy][wx]!=1){

    map[wy][wx]=1;

    }else{
        return;
    }
    
                
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
                whiteMove(wx+xpos[i],wy+ypos[i],map,limit-1);   
            
    }
        
}
```

input example:

1 => the amount of test case

3 => movement limit

A1 =>starting coordinate

th result is

Case #1:

0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0

1     0     1     0     1     0     0     0

1     1     1     0     0     1     0     0

1     0     1     1     1     0     0     0

*0    1     0     1     0     1     0     0  *map[5][0]

1      0   *1     1     1     0     0     0  *map[6][2]

1     1     1     0    *0     1     0     0  *map[7][4]

as you can see theres some place that should be '1' but for some reason is not, for example:

map[5][0] and map[7][4] should be '1' because map[6][2] is  '1', i dunno whats the problem with my code but my asumption is maybe the coordinate is visited twice, but i already make limitation about the coordinate, so i dont know wheres the problem.

0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0

0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0

0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0

1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0

0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0

1    1    0    0    1    0    0    0

0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0

1    0    1    0    1    0    0    0

this is the result when the movement limit is 2.

as you can see map[5][0] and map[7][4] is '1' as it should be.

any help will be apreciated, thank you

Comment: i corrected it,sorry for the typo @chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: Tip: Rather than `map[wy][wx]!=1 ... map[wy][wx]=1;`, use `map[wy][wx] == 0 ... map[wy][wx]=limit;` to better report what is happening.

Comment: Note that this code is doing a [Depth-First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), while it should probably be doing a [Breadth-First search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Answer (score 0):

> what did I do wrong?

Stopping, when recursion should go on.

---

`else if (map[wy][wx] != 1) {` and  `map[wy][wx] = 1` are problems.

The test `map[wy][wx] != 1` is simple asking, have I been here before?  But that is not enough.

The test should be have I been here before in less moves?

If during the tour, it is possible to get to a square in fewer moves, then the recursion from that point needs to go deeper, even though the square has been visited.

---

Two changes I made help see this, but do not solve it.  Leave that for OP.  (Note there are many ways to solve this.)

```
  if (wx < 0 || wy < 0 || wx > 7 || wy > 7 || limit == 0) {
    return;
  //  } else if (map[wy][wx] != 1) {
  } else if (map[wy][wx] == 0) {

    // map[wy][wx] = 1;
    map[wy][wx] = limit;

  } else {
    return;
  }

Case #1: 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
2 1 2 0 0 1 0 0 
1 0 1 2 1 0 0 0 
0 3 0 1 0 1 0 0 
1 0(1)2 1 0 0 0 From this square, recursion should go deeper ...
4 1 2 0(0)1 0 0 ... to get to this square.
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, haha... as someone who just learn recursion yesterday this thing is harder than I thought, but I'll try to solve it.